# Why do I receive NULL when fetching coordinates with the google maps API?

Tags: qt, google-maps, qt4, geolocation

I am trying to fetch the coordinates of a specific location using the Google Maps API, but I am getting coordinates as `NULL`. I am able to connect to a slot, but when I try to read the replied data, it comes back as `NULL` (When I do  `reply->readAll()`, it comes back as NULL).

Here is the sample code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
     manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    bool val = connect( manager, SIGNAL( finished (QNetworkReply *) ), this,
             SLOT (finished(QNetworkReply *) ) );

     QUrl request( "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo" );
     request.addQueryItem( "q", "New York" );
     request.addQueryItem( "sensor", false );
     request.addQueryItem( "output", "csv" );
     request.addQueryItem( "key","ABQIAAAAEeYlVIrQ3v9fkg9uOreI8RQG9ySifjUFt_tfsIL5mrcfjg4w7xREocRv0kD1cjJ893_O8Jqfhe4YMA" );
     manager->get( QNetworkRequest(request));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::finished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QString replyStr = reply->readAll();

}
```

Comment: please check `reply->error()` and `reply->errorString()`. tell us what error you're getting.

Comment: Hi, it says "Host maps.google.com not found".. what we need to do now?

Comment: what kind of device is the code running on? does it have internet access? is it's DNS set up properly?

Comment: i am running on My Desktop.. the code which i have written there is fine ?

Comment: Yes, the code looks good and the error you're getting has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Oh.. but i have downloaded a sample application, in that application it works well.. i just took a part and tried run standalone its giving some problem

Comment: Hi Mat, which environment r u using?.. can you please run my code once?

Comment: @LLL: the error you are getting is a DNS resolver issue. I can't reproduce that.

Comment: Hey, That problem is solved.. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

We need to add the below line to enable system proxy

```
  QNetworkProxyFactory::setUseSystemConfiguration(true);
```